# How to create a sorted list given two already sorted lists ( cannot modify either given lists )

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, function, sorting

My goal is to create a function that takes 2 lists of sorted ints as arguments
and creates a sorted merged list. The only problem is that I am not allowed to 
modify the 2 original lists ( and cant make duplicates to modify either ). Only allowed built-ins are range(), len(), index(), append(). So far I am stumped.

Here is what I have:

```
def merge_lists( list1, list2 ):

sortedList = []

pointer1 = 0

pointer2 = 0

while pointer1 < len( list1 ) and pointer2 < len( list2 ):

    if list1[ pointer1 ] < list2[ pointer2 ]:

        sortedList.append( list1[ pointer1 ] )

        pointer1 += 1

    elif list2[ pointer2 ] < list1[ pointer1 ]:

        sortedList.append( list2[ pointer2 ] )

        pointer2 += 1

    elif list1[ pointer1 ] == list2[ pointer2 ]:

        sortedList.append( list1[ pointer1 ] )

        sortedList.append( list2[ pointer2 ] )

        pointer1 += 1

        pointer2 += 1

if pointer1 == 0:

    for number in list1:

        sortedList.append( number )

if pointer2 == 0:

    for number in list2:

        sortedList.append( number )

else:

    amountNumbersLeft1 = len( list1 ) - ( pointer1 - 1 )

    amountNumbersLeft2 = len( list2 ) - ( pointer2 - 1 )

    if amountNumbersLeft1 != 0:

        for o in range( 1, ( amountNumbersLeft1 ) ):

            sortedList.append( list1[ o ] )

    if amountNumbersLeft2 != 0:

        for i in range( 1, ( amountNumbersLeft2 ) ):

            sortedList.append( list2[ i ] )

return sortedList
```

My test case with ( [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4, 5, 6 ] ) as the argument worked, returning a list [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]. My test case with ( [ 2, 13, 19 ], [ 3, 6, 9, 22 ] ) however, returned [ 2, 3, 6, 9, 13, 19, 6 ].

I feel that there is a much simpler sorting solution. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Please do not post links to screen shots of code, instead include it in your post.

Comment: It's better to provide code as text (can be formatted as code in the post), so we can make changes and test them. Nobody here is interested in manual typing the code into a file!

Comment: [`list(heapq.merge(first_list, second_list))`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge)?

Comment: ok I will do that!

Comment: This code would be a lot simpler if you iterate directly over your input list items instead of doing it indirectly with indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is actually a lot simpler than what you wrote.

```
def merge_lists(list1, list2):
    sortedList = []
    pointer1 = 0
    pointer2 = 0

    while pointer1 < len(list1) and pointer2 < len(list2):
        if list1[pointer1] < list2[pointer2]:
            sortedList.append(list1[pointer1])
            pointer1 += 1
        elif list1[pointer1] > list2[pointer2]:
            sortedList.append(list2[pointer2])
            pointer2 += 1
        else:
            sortedList.append(list1[pointer1])
            pointer1 += 1

    while pointer1 < len(list1):
        sortedList.append(list1[pointer1])
        pointer1 += 1

    while pointer2 < len(list2):
        sortedList.append(list2[pointer2])
        pointer2 += 1

    return sortedList
```

The problem with your code is that `pointer1` and `pointer2` will never be 0 since you increment them. Therefore you always execute the else branch of the `pointer2 == 0` condition. The logic in the else statement is wrong because you're adding numbers again from index 1 as stated in the for loop. That's why you add 6 again instead of 22, it's the value at index 1 of your second list in your example.

Comment: I ran this code for the second test case and it returned [2, 3, 6, 9, 13, 19]. I am still missing the last element of my list, the 22. Any ideas why?

Comment: @bariox i had a typo in the second while loop. it should have been `len(list2)` instead of `len(list1)`, the code is now fixed in the answer.

Comment: Ah thanks man I accepted your answer. Thanks everyone who replied helped me out a lot.

Answer (score 0):

That's fairly simple. Merge the lists using + and then use the sorted function.

```
merged = sorted(list1 + list2)
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that the built-in sorted function isnt allow. *fixed

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop to iterate over both the lists and keep appending the smaller value and incrementing corresponding index is correct.

```
   def merge_lists( list1, list2 ):

       sortedList = []
       pointer1 = 0
       pointer2 = 0

       while pointer1 < len( list1 ) and pointer2 < len( list2 ):
           if list1[ pointer1 ] < list2[ pointer2 ]:
               sortedList.append( list1[ pointer1 ] )
               pointer1 += 1
           elif list2[ pointer2 ] < list1[ pointer1 ]:
               sortedList.append( list2[ pointer2 ] )
               pointer2 += 1
           elif list1[ pointer1 ] == list2[ pointer2 ]:
               sortedList.append( list1[ pointer1 ] )
               sortedList.append( list2[ pointer2 ] )
               pointer1 += 1
               pointer2 += 1
```

It's all good till this point. The error happens afterwards. At this point of time at least one of the lists have been exhausted. So, you simply need to run 2 *for* loops to add the remaining numbers from the non exhausted list.

```
   while pointer1 < len( list1 ):
       sortedList.append( list1[ pointer1 ] )
       pointer1 += 1

   while pointer2 < len( list2 ):
       sortedList.append( list2[ pointer2 ] )
       pointer2 += 1

   return sortedList
```

Plain and simple :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `amountNumbersLeft1 = len( list1 ) - ( pointer1 - 1 )` line: In your second set of test data, the `len( list1 )` function will return 4. and the `pointer1` will be 3 since it's pointing to index 3. `(4  - ( 3 - 1))` is 2, which is the index you output.

I think what you really want is `for o in range( pointer1, len( list1 )-1 ):`